# Angular ng-repeat show data before the filter is applied

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

so I've got a ng-repeat with filters applied which works great! but when i load this there is nothing showing in the table. After I've applied the filters then the data shows and when I delete the filters aka the queries then all the data shows on the table.

So my question is how do I make the table show all the data aka the content and only apply the filters when I write in the inputs....

Thanks!

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <h1>HearthDB</h1>
        Class: <input ng-model="classQuery">
        Cost: <input ng-model="costQuery">
        </br>
        Type "Spell/Minion": <input ng-model="typeQuery">
        Secret: <input ng-model="secretQuery">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Cost</th>
                    <th>Text</th>
                    <th>Class</th>
                </tr>  
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="content in data | filter:{playerClass: classQuery, cost: costQuery, type: typeQuery, text: secretQuery}" ng-if="content.collectible && content.cost">
                    <th>{{content.name}}</th>
                    <th>{{content.type}}</th>
                    <th>{{content.cost}}</th>
                    <th ng-bind-html="to_trusted(content.text)"></th>
                    <th>{{content.playerClass}}</th>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
```

Comment: Does the filter variable show some value or seem uninitialized in angular-batarang or ng-inspector when the page is initialized? Just a hunch, since it sounds like everything works once some interaction has happened...

Comment: I just solved the problem I'll put my code up to help people that have this problem!

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys this is what i needed to solve my problem. hope this helps

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <h1>HearthDB</h1>
        Class: <input ng-model="classQuery.playerClass">
        Cost: <input ng-model="costQuery.cost">
        </br>
        Type "Spell/Minion": <input ng-model="typeQuery.type">
        Secret: <input ng-model="secretQuery.text">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Attack</th>
                    <th>Health</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Cost</th>
                    <th>Text</th>
                    <th>Class</th>
                </tr>  
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                   <tr ng-repeat="content in data | filter: classQuery | filter: costQuery | filter: typeQuery | filter: secretQuery" ng-if="content.collectible && content.cost">

                    <th>{{content.name}}</th>
                    <th>{{content.attack}}</th>
                    <th>{{content.health}}</th>
                    <th>{{content.type}}</th>
                    <th>{{content.cost}}</th>
                    <th ng-bind-html="to_trusted(content.text)"></th>
                    <th>{{content.playerClass}}</th>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
```